# How to disallow a view to display user's label (and some other fields?) when the user access is not allowed

Tags: views

I have created a very simple `UserAccessControlHandler` which return `AccessResult::forbidden()` is all cases:

```
 class MyUserAccessControlHandler extends UserAccessControlHandler {

  protected $viewLabelOperation = FALSE;

  protected function checkAccess(EntityInterface $user, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
}

function my_module_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $user = $entity_types['user'];
  $user->setAccessClass('Drupal\my_module\Access\MyUserAccessControlHandler');
}
```

it is working fine: Nobody can access a user profile.

But, If I create a view listing all users in a table with 3 columns:

- column 1 : name of the user (+link to the profile)
- column 2 : a custom field value of the user
- column 3 : the langcode field of the user (not sure what is this field, it looks like it is the original language code when the user has been encoded)

I was expecting that the view was empty for all regular users... but not!

The view display all users with the following information:

- column 1 : The name (without the link)
- column 2 : empty (has expected)
- column 3 : the langcode of the user

**My question is**: is it a bug or did I miss something?

**Edit to add**: I solve this problem by implementing a `checkFieldAccess` function which allow the access of the `name` field (and some others) only if the account have access to the user: `$access = $user->access($operation)` [There is also the case of the user creation, but it is not my topic]

It is working, but I feel this is not the way to go (if there is no access to the user then there should be no FieldAccess at all)... My question remains.